# Explain Why This Happens Please

Tags: php

I'm watching a tutorial on OOP for PHP, and I've come to the constructor/destructor segment.  When I instantiate an object, it obviously goes through the constructor, then it deconstructs it.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

  class Person {

    var $first_name;
    var $last_name;

    function __construct($firstName, $lastName) {

      $this->first_name = $firstName;
      $this->last_name = $lastName;

      echo 'Hi, my name is: ' . $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name . '!<br>';

    }

      function __destruct() {

        echo "Class objects are now being destroyed!<br>";

      }

  }

  $person1 = new Person('Ringo', 'Starr');
  $person2 = new Person('John', 'Lennon');

?>
```

Now when I run my code, it echoes back:

```
Hi, my name is: Ringo Starr!
Hi, my name is: John Lennon!
Class objects are now being destroyed!
Class objects are now being destroyed!
```

But, logically, at least in my mind, shouldn't the code echo:

```
Hi, my name is: Ringo Starr!
Class objects are now being destroyed!
Hi, my name is: John Lennon!
Class objects are now being destroyed!
```

Since I instantiate one object, so it goes through the motions, then it creates a new one?  This is pretty inconsequential, but I just want to understand the inner workings of programming.

Thanks all.

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Objects are destroyed not when you create new ones.

Comment: All objects are destroyed when the script is done executing.

Comment: Or when you manually destroy it (with `unset` for example)

Comment: @AbraCadaver so in theory I could instantiate a trillion objects, and the destructor won't execute until the end of the script?

Comment: Yes, how would you use them if they are destroyed before the end of the script?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#language.oop5.decon.destructor

Comment: That's actually a really good question/point.  In my head, they get constructed, then destructed.  Since, in theory, the object was already used the way it was meant to, it could be destroyed.  I'm kind of awkward at explaining things, do you get what I mean?

Comment: @u_mulder Thanks, that actually helps a lot.

Comment: `the object was already used the way it was meant to, it could be destroyed` Who can tell - if object was used or will be used later? Only the developer. That's why if you need to destroy an object - call `unset` for example. Otherwise all objects will exists until the end of script.

Comment: @u_mulder That's a fair point.  I guess I thought programming was pseudo-intuitive.  Thanks for all the help guys!

Comment: Also do one of you want to throw an answer here so I can accept it?

Comment: objects are destroyed at the end of executing every other code. if not, then it means that we would be creating new instance of db connection n every single class.

Comment: As a separate note - A `destructor` is  very rarely needed.  So, it may be interesting to learn about but you are unlikely to use it or need it.

Comment: @RyanVincent I figured it was pretty rarely used, but I was just curious about it.  Thanks for the info, though!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

//Just for Explaination
function funcContext()
{//CONTEXT EXISTS
    $person1 = new Person('Ringo', 'Starr');
    // person1 __constructed
    //"Hi, my name is: Ringo Starr!"
    //alive

    $person2 = new Person('John', 'Lennon');
    // person2 __constructed
    // "Hi, my name is: John Lennon!"
    // alive

    //They will remain alive till this context

}//CONTEXT DESTROYED
//they will be destroyed
//"Class objects are now being destroyed!"
//"Class objects are now being destroyed!"
```

Comment: Please write an explanation what is the problem with the code in the question, and why this answer is actually an answer to the question. Comments in the code are nice to have, but an introduction and a conclusion to your suggestion is also needed.